# Finding max element of array using parallel method - divide array on to 2 parts (without using any loops)

Tags: arrays, max

As I mentioned in the title, the question is how to find max element of array, using parallel method - by dividing array on 2 parts (from beginning to half of array, and from the half to end) without using loops.
So we have to find max1 and max2 and return bigger one.
Can someone tell me idea or algorithm?
Thanks

Comment: What does “without loops” mean? You clearly can’t do this in one step, and you can’t write it all out in advance, so a loop is crucial. You might use recursion but that is still a loop. Is this a homework problem? If so, say so and quote it accurately.

Comment: Sounds like a good candidate for binary search - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm

Comment: Yep it should do like recursion. Sorry for not saying. Thats why i cant use loops

Comment: And array is not sorted

Comment: On second thoughts, you don't need to search at all.  Split the array into two, sort those arrays, return the greatest value from each, return greatest value from comparing them.  Each of those steps could be made into functions.

Comment: It should work like recursion. Also the function parallel_max has parameters *p and *q, where p is pointer of beginning of array, and q is one place after end of array. If q==p+1 it should return *p

Comment: In your function if the array length is greater than 1 pick an element in the middle and call the function (recurse) twice: once for the array from the start to immediately before that element, and once from that element to the end. Compare the two values returned from the calls and return the biggest one.  As you say, if the array passed in is length one just return the value of that element.  That's not very efficient but it's easy to write and I suspect the question is trying to get you to understand recursion.